# segfault in libc-2.23.so on boot

Tags: boot, lubuntu

I'm running Lubuntu 16.04 on my laptop, and today I booted it up to a nasty surprise:

```
[     10.327245] systemd[1]: segfault at 20 ip 00007f66bcb38362 sp 00007ffc9f8ea848 error 6 in libc-2.23.so[7f66bca91000+1c0000]
[     10.327760] systemd[1]: Caught <SEGV>, core dump failed (child 207, code=killed, status=11/SEGV).
[     10.327847] systemd[1]: Freezing execution.
```

Restarting it manually puts my into the GRUB boot menu, with the Ubuntu/Advanced options/System setup options, my advanced options are `Ubuntu, with Linux 4.13.0-45-generic` or `4.13.0-43-generic`, both with recovery mode options.

I'm pretty out of my depth here haha, is there anything I can do to salvage this (really don't want to lose what's on my HD right now) or is it pretty much screwed?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, this is caused by an update to Libre Office- I'd downloaded an update just before this started happening.

I'm taking what I can off with a USB boot stick running in "try Ubuntu" mode, then reinstalling, since there doesn't seem to be a way to uninstall programs from this mode- if anyone knows of one that'd be useful.